# CSS-only: Show element whilst input is selected

Tags: html, css

I have an element that I would like to show when an input field is selected, but it is preferential that I don't use any JavaScript to do this.

Since I can't put the element within the input field (obviously), I cannot target it in my CSS for when the input field is active (I assume that the :active selector can be used on an input field that is currently selected rather than having your mouse clicked down on it).

At the moment I have a structure like so:

```
<div class="outer">
  <input type="text" name="field" />
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Is there anyway with the `:root` selector or something similar to target a parent element after `:active`?

My CSS now:

```
.element {
  display: none;
}

.outer:active .element {
  display: block;
}
```

This essentially works, however the element is only shown whilst you hold your click down anywhere within the outer element, and I don't want to use `:hover`, completely stuck here and I've had a search round and couldn't find much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/gu531aay/3/

```css
.element {
  display: none;
}
input:focus ~ .element {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <input type="text" name="field" />
  <div class="element">hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 - I've never seen that before, that's super useful.

Comment: I had no idea you could do that! Thank you very much, I'll be using this almost every day now haha, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It will show immediate next div to input element which is inside `outer` element when input field inside outer is focused.

```css
.element {
  display: none;
}

.outer input:focus + .element {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <input type="text" name="field" />
  <div class="element">hello</div>
</div>
```